# Excel chart axis with personal label instead of number

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, charts, axis

I'm a simpleton with excel but writing a research dissertation. Much charting involved...

My y axis has values 0-6 but each number represents a patient response (for example `never`, `very rarely`, `rarely`, `occasionally`, `often`, `very often`, `extremely often`)

How do I change the ticks on the y axis to read that instead of 0-6 so those reading the paper don't have to refer to a legend?

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?  Your question on top of that isn't exactly clear.

Comment: Didn't mean it to have that title. Will change it (if I can)

Comment: How can you have Excel 2013 on OSX?? I think the latest version is 2011 for Mac?

Comment: @ṧнʊß - **It is.**  I didn't even notice that.

Comment: Any thoughts on the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your description, this is pretty straightforward. Just change those 1-6's to the textual indicators, as below:

[image]

I just selected the data and hit 'Insert Chart' — the result was the graph that you see.